# Is it possible to let Siri push button in swift app?

Tags: swift, watchkit, siri

Is it possible to ask Siri to push buttons in the app with the text to speech? 
I mean, I have a calculator and pushing the button of "dictation" Siri should be able to understand to push + button instead of just write inside the lable the text.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Siri cannot be used inside apps. Moreover, you can only use Siri for [handling intents](https://developer.apple.com/sirikit/) that are part of the `SiriKit` framework, which is quite limited at the moment.

[VoiceOver](https://developer.apple.com/accessibility/watchos/) is perfectly capable of what you need to do. It was designed for navigating through an app with voice commands as part of the Accessibility framework.

The [Speech framework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/speech) as suggested by others is not available in `watchOS` and wasn't really designed for voice navigation.

Comment: Does this answer also apply to iOS or only watchOS?

Comment: @Honey the Siri part applies to both platforms. The `Speech` framework is available on iOS, but it is still quite hacky to use it for navigation inside the app. This is one of VoiceOver's main features, so that is the framework that should be used for this on iOS as well.

Comment: For my case I have just implemented the dictation and then red char by char what was on the dictation and using what was dictated for start some functions.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use Speech framework for that. It would not be possible with Siri. You can go through [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/speech) for that.

Comment: Do you think it's possible through the Speech framework to let understand to push a button and not just to write text?

Comment: You will need to write your recogniser for that. You will not need to actually push the button . You can call call the selector for push button directly. Lets say your are recognising what user Speaks, you find out that user says 'ADD', you can perfrom the add action in this condition.